# install opencv from source windows

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV following this link https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html

opencv-4.5.1 is the version I am building from source. I have no errors in my entire process( up to Step 16)
Step 17 which INSTALL also has no errors, but Step 18 'import cv2 as cv' will not import this module.

I have python 3.9.1. I followed all the steps with CMAKE and was able to generate with no errors.
Is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use another IDE like Pycharm to create your projects. It is extremely easy to setup an OpenCV work environment :).
IDLE is great for smaller projects but I`ve seen a lot of people having issues with it.